# discord.py BS4 can't get info out of href element

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, discord, discord.py

I have the following HTML:

```
<a href="//site.com/user/123/Username1"><img height="56px" src="//s.site.com/user/123/avatar" width="56px"/>Username</a>
```

How can I get "Username1" before the `</a>` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.text` property:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = '''<a href="//site.com/user/123/Username1"><img height="56px" src="//s.site.com/user/123/avatar" width="56px"/>Username</a>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

print(soup.a.text)
```

Prints:

```
Username
```

---

If you want to parse the username from `href="..."` attribute:

```
print(soup.a['href'].split('/')[-1])
```

Prints:

```
Username1
```